# Combine MYSQL query in one GridView

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView showing some data from a MYSQL database. I would like to show all Donations and have Total_Donations at the bottom.

It seems I can do either or but not both.

Does anyone know how to do this?

**My Code(This shows all Donations)**

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Donation FROM Customer", cs);
            cs.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dgl = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dg.DataSource = dgl;
            dg.DataBind();
            cs.Close();
```

**My Code(This shows total)**

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Donation) AS Total_Donation FROM Customer", cs);
        cs.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dgl = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dg.DataSource = dgl;
        dg.DataBind();
        cs.Close();
```

Any way of of showing all donations and then total at the bottom?  Even if I have to put it in a Label, although would be best in same table.

Comment: Are you using a DataGridView (WinForms) or a GridView (ASP.NET webforms)? It's...unclear from your question, since you tagged ASP.NET, but you mention DataGridView.

Comment: I am using web forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could display the FooterRow in your GridView:

```
dg.ShowFooter = True;
```

Then you just set one of the cells to the total value that you have gotten from your database:

```
dg.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text = totalDonations;
```

Where "totalDonations" is the value you queried from your database.

I would write that code in your GridView's DataBound event.  Something like this:

```
protected void dg_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Donation) AS Total_Donation FROM Customer", cs);
    cs.Open();
    string totalDonations = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    cs.Close();
    dg.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text = totalDonations;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I did not know about the footer row. Ill shall give it a try.